# Como controlar eventos em C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

Usando a classe "TcpListener" estou "escutando" uma porta onde vários clientes vão se conectar. Até ai tranquilo. Pra fazer a recepção dos dados de um cliente eu usei uma Thread que gera um evento sempre que algum dado é recebido. 
Porém ao criar o evento não consigo ter uma ideia de como saber qual evento pertence a qual cliente. Obs: os clients estão em uma List.

```
    private async void btnAceitarClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ServerTCP.Started)
        {
            await ServerTCP.AddAllPendingClients();

            if (ServerTCP.clientList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ServerTCP.clientList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ServerTCP.clientList[i].Connected)
                    {
                        Log.print(richTextBox1, Log.tipo.Controlador, string.Format("\r\nIP Conectado : {0}", ServerTCP.clientList[i].IP));

                        //Gera evento de recepçao.
                        ServerTCP.clientList[i].DataReceivedInBackGround += FrmControllers_Conector_DataReceivedInBackGround;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.print(richTextBox1, Log.tipo.Controlador, "\r\nCliente aceito mas não conectado.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.print(richTextBox1, Log.tipo.Controlador, "\r\nNão há clientes na lista.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void FrmControllers_Conector_DataReceivedInBackGround(object source, EventArgs e)
    {

        Log.print(richTextBox1, Log.tipo.Controlador, ServerTCP.clientList[QUAL CLIENTE É ESTE???].Read());

    }
```

Comment: Normalmente, essas informações vem no eventargs...

Comment: Tentei fazer algo do tipo:" int i = ServerTCP.clientList.FindIndex(e.XXXXX); " mas não sei como.

Comment: Boa tarde! Analisando sua necessidade, vejo que talvez o ideal seria você trabalhar com SignalR, é um socket C#, muito bom, com ele você consegue saber quais o usuários estão conectados. Mandar mensagem para um usuário especifico, grupo de usuários ou todos o usuários. é muito facil de utilizar. Sempre indico este artigo do site do Eduardo Pires, é pratico e de facil didática, aprendi com ele. Hoje utilizo em todos meus projetos. http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/aspnet-signalr-introducao-e-utilizacao/

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

```
    private void FrmControllers_Conector_DataReceivedInBackGround(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Identifico o index do cliente que chamou o evento na lista de clients
        int i = ServerTCP.clientList.FindIndex(source.Equals);
        //Printo no log o IP e a Mensagem recebida.
        Log.print(richTextBox1, Log.tipo.Controlador, string.Format("[{0}] : {1} ", ServerTCP.clientList[i].IP, ServerTCP.clientList[i].Read()));
    }
```